# Update custom table on metabox POST

Tags: custom-field, metabox, wpdb, table, phpmyadmin

So here is the problem : I have created a metabox field for my posts and I want it to update a custom table (wp_location) in my WP datase... The idea is to update the table with the value of the POST method, but for some reason I seem to be using wrong the "wpdb" thing and it crashes every time on update... Here is my code for now :

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes','initialisation_metaboxes');
function initialisation_metaboxes() {
    add_meta_box('idMetaBox','test metabox','meta_function','post','side','high');
}

function meta_function(){
  echo '<label for="my_field">Test field : </label>';
  echo '<input id="my_field" type="text" name="my_field" />';
}

function save_metaboxes(){
  if(isset($_POST['my_field'])){
    $wpdb->update('wp_location', array('latitude' =>  $_POST['my_field']), array('refPost' => 198) );
  }

}

add_action('save_post','save_metaboxes');
```

I'm very new to Wordpress and metaboxes but I just can't find the solutions after hours of forum research...

My table is run in PhpMyAdmin and contains only 3 field for now :

- idLoc (autoincremented by PhpMyAdmin)
- refPost (I've inserted the value manually here - 198 - but there must be some easy way to retrieve it)
- latitude (which is a simple text field for the moment)

Thanks for your help T_T

I know I could be using the post_meta table and functions, but I need a more complex database structure...

Comment: What means "it crashes"? What exactly happens? Any error message? Something in server logs?

Comment: I have an error 500 when I save my edits on post and of course the table is not updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) - you need to globalise `$wpdb` before you can use it inside your function:

```
function save_metaboxes() {
    global $wpdb;

    // Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: It worked just fine. I had tried to globalise $wpdb outside the function, when it had to be inside in order to work... Thanks a lot!